# Can I use a cool pad instead of CPU fan if it's broken?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling

My laptop fan is getting so annoying, so I was thinking to pull its cable off for a month and just use a cool pad instead. I was wondering whether it's a good idea or not. I'm working in a room with a temperature of 18-22 Celcius and I don't do any CPU intensive work on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, starting a computer and especially a laptop without adequate cooling hardware is done at your own risk. Many modern processors are designed to thermal throttle and even go so far as to shut down if temperatures become dangerous to your hardware, but this will require you to consult documentation and even then I'm unsure if you'll get a conclusive answer.

In your case, I would suggest just ordering a replacement fan and installing it if you are having trouble with the current one.

Laptops are much worse at dissipating heat than desktops, and [some enthusiasts](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/safe-to-run-a-pc-without-a-system-fan.2886169/) are even torn on whether or not you can run a desktop CPU with no fan, even with a massive dedicated heat sink. This just casts further doubt that a cooling pad will be sufficient.

Risks aside, if you want to try disabling the fan and using just a cooling pad, you should determine what temperature your laptop currently runs at:

1. Download temperature monitoring software. CPUID provides a good, free temperature monitor that I've seen reputable sources use, but anything that will track temperatures will do.
2. Before disabling your fan, start your computer, open the temperature monitoring software, and use your computer normally.
3. Note the maximum temperature that your CPU reaches.
4. Leave your computer idling for 5 minutes.
5. Note the idle temperature that your CPU hovers around.

Many laptops will reach high temperatures even without CPU intensive tasks because they simply lack mass in their heat sinks. Thermal throttling should prevent you from reaching 100°C, because this temperature is what manufacturers consider to be too high. Enthusiasts will tell you 80° to 90° should be avoided, but in a laptop it can be unreasonable to avoid these temperatures. Regardless, if your CPU idles in the 80°+ range I would recommend against even trying to disable the fan. If you're idling at something like 60° and you're not maxing out at 100°, then your strategy may work.

You will have to keep an eye on your temperatures while using your computer without the fan. Specifically, repeat the above steps and note the new temperatures. If you are reaching or surpassing 100°, especially at idle, you should re-enable the fan.

Regardless of the results, a cooling fan is preferred and you should try to replace it or use it if possible.

Comment: thank you for your answer.